# DefaultHttpClient post get session cookie and pass to WebView android

Tags: android, webview, httpclient, session-cookies

I've found a few answers to this question here on SO, but I'm not having success implementing them so hoped that someone could check over my code and tell me where i'm going wrong.

I have verified that my cookie is being set from the DefaultHttpClient and am writing it out with Log.d as you can see in my code snippet below.  It's all there, it's just not getting set for the WebView which is called at the bottom of this code segment.  The cookie being passed down is a session cookie from my Asp.net mvc project.  Any ideas why it's not keeping me logged in when the WebView hits the site?  Don't let the facebook wording throw you off, that I all have working, this cookie is for my own server that is passing down a session cookie to keep me logged into my own site (based on my facebook stuff).

```
Cookie sessionCookie = FacebookLoginService.cookie;
Log.d("intialwebview",sessionCookie.toString());
CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
if (sessionCookie != null) {
    cookieManager.removeSessionCookie();
    String cookieString = sessionCookie.getName() + "=" + sessionCookie.getValue() + "; domain=" + sessionCookie.getDomain();
    Log.d("intialwebview",cookieString);
    cookieManager.setCookie(FacebookLoginService.cookie.getDomain(), cookieString);
    CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
}  
//end cookie section


int userId = prefs.getInt(C.USER_ID, 0);
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);
webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(webView.getSettings().getUserAgentString() + "(Rambo)");
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY); 
webView.loadUrl(C.BaseUrl + "home/firstpage");
```

**EDIT:**  I also tried creating the web view in code with:

```
WebView webView = new WebView(this);
```

same result.  Cookie isn't being sent to the webview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally got this sorted by using an Asynctask and running a sleep in the background.

Comment: Hi Christopher, I am getting same problem. last day it was working fine on android 4.1.2. Today it is not working on 4.0.3. 
I followed same procedure. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You have used this line -

```
if (sessionCookie != null) {
  cookieManager.removeSessionCookie();
  }
```

To ensure you receive new cookie everytime.
Seems like you have gone through same issue
as I faced, check below link -

[removeSessionCookie() issue of android, (code.google.com)](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=16543)

it says that `removeSessionCookie()` is implemented in a thread, so whenever it is

called; a thread starts and after your `setCookie(url, cookieString);` is called,

it removes the new cookie you just set. 
So for some devices it works well as `removeSessionCookie()` is already executed,

while, for some, it remove the cookie, and we get that problem.

I suggest you remove this `removeSessionCookie();` as you are setting only one cookie, so it won't conflict with other cookies. Your code will work seamlessly.